# wget or alternative command line to download pdf files that are stored on dropbox and linked to from my domain

Tags: command-line, download, command, wget

I am looking for wget or alternative command line to download pdf files that are stored on dropbox and linked to from my domain. This is what I have come up with so far but I think my structure is incorrect.

```
wget --recursive --level=3 --no-directories --no-host-directories --reject-regex cat --reject-regex dog --accept-regex snake --accept-regex dropbox.com --accept pdf http://example.com/dogs-cats-snakes/snakes/files/main/
```

I want wget to start at http://example.com/dogs-cats-snakes/snakes/files/main/ go up to 3 levels deep to look for dropbox links with a pdf file in it. I think the first problem is the link it starts from has dog and cat in url, I don't want it to ignore the links inside the first one but ignore any other links with dog / cat going forward. It is weird because testing my command without "--accept-regex dropbox.com" in it, I still see it crawling cat and dog pages and not only snake pages, I don't know why. So there is definitely something wrong. If it does continue to follow links with dog / cat in url, it will find thousands of links that don't have the the correct pdf files I want and will take ages to go through everything. I only want pdf files that are linked to from snake pages wheter it is plural or not. The other condition is I only want pdf files that are stored on dropbox.com and not any other site.

Comment: I don't think wget allows multiple accept/reject args. they won't get added together into a single regex - the last one will simply overwrite all the previous ones, so you're accepting dropbox and rejecting dogs, as listed above. you'd have to do `--reject-regex '(dog|cat)'` or whatever.

Comment: I thought it now worked using 

wget --recursive --level=3 --no-directories --no-host-directories --reject-regex "(cat|dog)" --accept-regex "(snake|dropbox.com)" --accept pdf http://example.com/dogs-cats-snakes/snakes/files/main/

because it said it saved 50 files or so but there no files to be found anywhere on my c:\ drive